# How to get daily backup mysql database on godday hosting based on cronjob

Tags: php, mysql, liveserver

i have issue to daily backup for mysql database.
export only all tables with data but not mysql function and stored procedure.
how to get full database backup?

I have use this cronjob.

mysqldump –opt -Q -h [myhost] -u myusername –p"*****" ebooklibrary > /fullpath.../_db_backups/openelibrary.sql

Comment: What exactly is your question? Since `-opt` is the default you don't need to specify it. You may also specify where the backup file goes, along with the name, in the call to `mysqldump`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "--routines" option, which is off by default in the query. This should give you the desired result. I hope this helps.
Read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-stored-programs.html).

```
mysqldump --routines –opt -Q -h [myhost] -u myusername –p"*****" ebooklibrary > /fullpath.../_db_backups/openelibrary.sql
```